# GBK Encode/Decode Charset

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, gbk

I am receiving a binary packet from a server containing the following:

```
var data = new Uint8Array([0xB2, 0xE2, 0xCA, 0xD4, 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33]);
```

I know it's a GBK charset and I am using the [TextDecoder/TextEncoder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) to read it back:

```
var str = TextDecoder('gbk').decode(data);
// result: 测试test123
```

Now, the question : **How to do the opposite ?**

I tested :

```
var data = TextEncoder().encode(str);
// but it doesn't match
```

Some handed compression:

```
(str.charCodeAt(0) & 0xff) | ((str.charCodeAt(1) >>> 8) & 0xff)
// but yeah, not need to be pro to know it can't works.
```

Does someone know a way to do the reverse operation ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

I used the shim: https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding
and commented a condition part in the TextEncoder constructor to allow other charset.

Here is an example:

```
if (this._encoding === null /*|| (this._encoding.name !== 'utf-8' &&
                                                                    this._encoding.name !== 'utf-16le' &&
                                                                    this._encoding.name !== 'utf-16be')*/)

throw new TypeError('Unknown encoding: ' + opt_encoding);
```